# Is there possible to add gps vocal navigation into my app?

Tags: iphone, ios6, gps

with the arrival of the vocal indication on IOS 6.
I want to know if is it possible to add this functionality to my app

Thanks,
Yasin

Answer (score 0):

Cloudmade http://cloudmade.com/products/navi-studio has some tools that could help you.

They provide a service that returns a XML representation of the route with turn by turn information included. You could feed this texts into a text to speech engine.